# How to use kile with feynmf or feynmp?

Tags: automation, kile, feynmf, build-system, feynman

Does somebody know how to teach `kile` to automatically do the additional steps for compiling Latex documents that contain Feynman diagrams produced with `feynmf` or `feynmp`?

For what I know I have to run `latex`, then run `mf title` (or for some reason `mf '\mode:=localfont;' input title`; `mpost` for feynmp) for every Feynman graph defined with

```
\begin{fmffile}{title}
  % the actual diagram definition
\end{fmffile}
```

and then run `latex` again. Can this conveniently be automized in `kile`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following works with `pdflatex` and **feynmp**:

```
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\makeatletter
\def\endfmffile{%
  \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
          end.^^J%
          endinput;}%
  \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
  \fi
  \ifnum\pdfshellescape=\@ne
    \immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

If you now call `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option (`-enable-write18` for MiKTeX), the Metapost file is compiled right after the end of the environment and will be used at the next compilation.

---

**NOTE** TeX Live 2012 lists `mpost` among the programs that can be run with "restricted shell escape", so the test above can be

```
  \ifnum\pdfshellescape>\z@
```

and `-shell-escape` is not needed any more. Note though that MiKTeX 2.9 *doesn't* allow `mpost` in restricted shell escape.

---

For **feynmf** it's just the same:

```
\usepackage{feynmf}

\makeatletter
\def\endfmffile{%
  \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
          end.^^J%
          endinput;}%
  \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
  \fi
  \ifnum\pdfshellescape=\@ne
    \immediate\write18{mf "\noexpand\mode:=localfont;input \thefmffile"}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Adding `-shell-escape` to the call of (pdf)latex should be easy in Kile.

I advise to use **feynmp** that's easier to manage and produces resolution independent output. Moreover it supports color.

Another way, for older systems, is to open an output stream where to write the necessary shell commands.

```
\usepackage{feynmf}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\@feynmfwr
\immediate\openout\@feynmfwr=\jobname.out
\def\endfmffile{%
  \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
          end.^^J%
          endinput;}%
  \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
  \fi
  \immediate\write\@feynmfwr{mf "\noexpand\mode:=localfont;input \thefmffile"}%
  }
\makeatother
```

At the end of the LaTeX run you'll have a file called as your main file, with extension `.out` that contains the necessary shell commands to run. If the file is `main.tex` all you have to do is to run from the shell

```
sh main.out
```

Comment: Is there any way to have this work with both `pdflatex` and `latex` at the same time? This neat trick results in `latex` complaining "Can not include graphics of type: mps." (If `mpost` has already run)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Can you try with `feynmp-auto` instead of `feynmp`? This should work without the need of any trick: the `feynmp-auto` package is just an implementation of the trick and loads `feynmp` automatically.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! (It didn't show up in MikTeX since I forgot to synchronize the repo...) In MikTeX, the `-enable-write18` switch does the trick for both `pdflatex` and `latex`, I think you mention that only in this post but not in the package documentation.

Comment: Minor bug-report: If one has run LaTeX (but not mpost) before switching to `feynmp-auto`, the already existing `.mp` file will not be considered "changed" and therefore `mpost` won't ever be run. A workaround is deleting all `.mp` files when switching to `feynmp-auto`. Maybe the package can check for the existence of processed diagrams as well?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Thanks for the remarks; I'll probably add a `force` option to disable the checks and run Metapost anyway. It's a pity that MiKTeX doesn't allow `mpost` in the restricted shell, but it may have something to do with how the program is built.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Version 1.1 is on its way to CTAN