# feynmf with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, metapost, metafont, feynmf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use kile with feynmf or feynmp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/how-to-use-kile-with-feynmf-or-feynmp)

I would like to use `feynmf`, or better `feynmp`, with `pdflatex`. My first idea was to replace all the files `file.[0-9]*` which are produced after running `mpost` on `file.mp` corresponding to a `\fmffile{file}` environment by their PDF version obtained with `epstopdf`. But unfortunately `pdflatex` complains

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .1.
```

Obviously it does not know the filetype from this extension. How can I tell LaTeX that these are PDF files? The names of the files do of course not appear explicitly in my LaTeX source.
Note that I looked at [How to use kile with feynmf or feynmp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/how-to-use-kile-with-feynmf-or-feynmp) which does not seem to work for me. Also I would prefer a solution which allows me to be able to compile with both `latex` and `pdflatex` (of course after generating the corresponding `feynmf` graph files). I do not mind running `feynmf` and `mpost` by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Metapost creates postscript files, so to include them in a `pdflatex`-processed document, you need to make an extra step.  One of the ways of doing it is to use the package `pst-pdf`.  Here is an example.

First, here is the document (`tmp.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{fmffile}{t}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,30) \fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2} \fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1} \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
\fmf{photon,label=$q$}{v1,v2} \fmfdot{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the stuff in postscript is inside `postscript` environment.

Now the workflow

```
latex tmp                 # Produces the metapost input
mpost t.mp                # Produces t.1 and t.t1.  Can be repeated
                          # for several Feynman diagrams
latex tmp                 # Creates the dvi file with figures
dvips -o tmp-pics.ps tmp  # Creates the ps file with figures
ps2pdf tmp-pics.ps        # Creates the pdf file with figures
pdflatex tmp              # Compiles the result
```

And the result:

[image]
    ps2pdf tmp-pics.ps

Comment: There is no need to do all those steps: what's sufficient is adding `\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}` to the document and running `mpost t`.

Comment: hmmm...  I agree.

Comment: Or just do `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` instead of `\usepackage{feynmp}`