# How to resize Feynman diagrams drawn with FeynMF / FeynMP (and their labels)?

Tags: dimensions, feynmf

This seems like an easy question, but I haven't found any hints on this, so: How do I resize the output of `FeynMF` and the labels within it?

I use it like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Feynman diagram:\\
    \begin{fmffile}{fgraph_tau}
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(8,5)
        \fmfleft{i1,i0}
        \fmfright{o1,o0}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$e^+$}{i1,w1}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\overline\nu_e$}{w1,o1}
        \fmf{boson,label=$W$}{w0,w1}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\overline\nu_\mu$}{i0,w0}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\mu^+$}{w0,o0}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
  ...
\end{enumerate}
```

and compile using [this SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22611/1442), which gives a nice Feynman diagram in the output pdf in the place I'd like it to be.

Now I would like to have a) the labels a bit larger and b) the overall graph itself a bit smaller. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The size of the diagram is controlled by `\unitlength`; you can also issue a font size changing command for increasing the size of the letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Feynman diagram:
    \begin{fmffile}{fgraph_tau}
      \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(8,5)
        \fmfleft{i1,i0}
        \fmfright{o1,o0}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$e^+$}{i1,w1}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\overline\nu_e$}{w1,o1}
        \fmf{boson,label=$W$}{w0,w1}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\overline\nu_\mu$}{i0,w0}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\mu^+$}{w0,o0}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}

  \item Smaller Feynman diagram:
    \begin{fmffile}{fgraph_tau2}
      \setlength{\unitlength}{.75cm}\large
      \begin{fmfgraph*}(8,5)
        \fmfleft{i1,i0}
        \fmfright{o1,o0}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$e^+$}{i1,w1}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\overline\nu_e$}{w1,o1}
        \fmf{boson,label=$W$}{w0,w1}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\overline\nu_\mu$}{i0,w0}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$\mu^+$}{w0,o0}
      \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the `\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}` command in my header. Thanks for the quick solution (as usual).