# Setting target directory for FeynMF's intermediate files?

Tags: auxiliary-files, feynmf

Related to "[How to use kile with feynmf or feynmp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20241/1442)", is it possible to tell the `feynmf` package where to place its intermediate files?

I sometimes have a lot of Feynman diagrams in my LaTeX documents, which are compiled using the solution provided in the previous question, but the files produced in the process clutter the directory with the tex source files.

Comment: Until recently, `mpost` did not honor the `-output-dir` option like other programs in the TeX family. This might be a future addition to `feynmp-auto`.